# How to load and run a TensorFlow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Super simple question.

I'm following this tutorial: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_image_retraining.ipynb

I've followed the instructions (not the optional part) trained a model, and have it saved using tf.saved_model.save

Now I want to run the model against a new picture. How do I do this?

I tried the following:

```
loaded = tf.saved_model.load("/tmp/saved_flowers_model")
print(list(loaded.signatures.keys()))  # ["serving_default"]

infer = loaded.signatures["serving_default"]
print(infer.structured_outputs)

file = .../pic.jpg
output = loaded (file)
```

which returned the following error:

```
ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
  Positional arguments (3 total):
    * /Users/dansafdie/Documents/Code Repos/Image Classifier/flower_photos/daisy/19834392829_7d697871f6.jpg
    * False
    * None
  Keyword arguments: {}

Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):

Option 1:
  Positional arguments (3 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
    * True
    * None
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 2:
  Positional arguments (3 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
    * False
    * None
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 3:
  Positional arguments (3 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1')
    * False
    * None
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 4:
  Positional arguments (3 total):
    * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1')
    * True
    * None
  Keyword arguments: {}
```